# Asterisk 1.8.13 with conferences on Synology DSM 4.3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: voip, asterisk, synology, conference

I have installed Asterisk 1.8.13 on a Synology NAS with DSM 4.3.
My problem is, that I can't call the conference.
I see this in Asterisk CLI:
`WARNING[15117]: pbx.c:4218 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'MeetMe' for extension (DLPN_DialPlan1, 6300, 1)
  == Spawn extension (DLPN_DialPlan1, 6300, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/6000-00000004'`

in **modules.conf** I have `autoload=yes`, but I don't have `load = app_meetme.so` and I don't have this app_meetme.so module in modules folder.

I tried to recompile Asterisk with DAHDI but on my system there is no **make** command and honestly I would like to try something easier solution first if possible. I don't want to mess everything up.

what do I need in order to make conferences work and what do I need to do? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSM by default have no dahdi.

You have compile it yourself, which is not trivial and require buildroot.

Also you can use ConfBridge application, it not require dahdi.